# Python3: Namespace AppIndicator3 not available

Tags: pygobject

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I have a Python program (program.py) that has this at the beginning:

```
import shlex
import sys
import notify2
import os
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

gi.require_version("AppIndicator3", "0.1")
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
```

When I run it, this is what happens:

```
$ python3 /path/to/program.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/program.py", line 34, in <module>
    gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 129, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace AppIndicator3 not available
```

Relevant info:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5

$ pip3 freeze
dbus-python==1.2.16
docutils==0.16
formiko==1.4.3
libxml2-python==2.9.10
meson==0.55.1
notify2==0.3.1
pycairo==1.19.1
PyGObject==3.36.1

$ brew install gobject-introspection
Warning: gobject-introspection 1.64.1_2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.64.1_2, run `brew reinstall gobject-introspection`
```

I also have the following installed:

```
libappindicator3-1 is already the newest version (12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1).
gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 is already the newest version (12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1).
python3-gi is already the newest version (3.26.1-2ubuntu1).
```

What might be keeping AppIndicator3 from being found?

Answer (score 3):

If you're having this issue while using pystray, try

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try taking off line 9 and import it directly.

Comment: FWIW, this is what made a similar issue work for me.

Answer (score 0):

in Fedora you need libappindicator-gtk3 installed

you need to have file /usr/lib64/girepository-1.0/AppIndicator3-0.1.typelib

i.e you need have gir sub-package installed in you are using other distro